# Нет иконок и не открываются прилоежния popos

Tags: ubuntu, icon, gnome

У меня popOs gnome 22.04 LTS
Я устанавливал уконки с сайта gnome-look.org через OCS. У меня открылась папка со всеми папками иконок и я хотел удалить которые не использую, но видимо отправил в корзину те, которые устновлены сейчас и у меня пропали все иконки, а также перестали открываться ВСЕ приложения кроме Opera и Telegram(предполагаю потому что они из flatpack)
Подскажите, что можно сделать ибо у меня вообще нет вариантов, у меня не открываются ни настройки ни терминал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пользовательские настройки программ нынче обыно в `~/.config`. переименуйте временно этот каталог. и перезапустите сеанс.

Comment: я не могу открыть ни терминал ни файловый менеджер

Comment: `alt+ctrl+f1`, `alt-ctrl-f2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Я зашел в терминал с помощью ctrl-alt-f3, а затем командой
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme ubuntu-mono` изменил тему иконок на рабочую